# bind a radiobuttonlist with dropdownlist postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am going to bind a radiobuttonlist with dropdownlist postback.for this i put two action in control but when the view loads an error :object refrence null
in fact before postback dropdown wants to bind radiobutton that this time object is null
please advise me

```
    namespace Charge.Models
    {
    public class SellChargeModel
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Serial { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Bank { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Companys { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> types { get; set; }

    public ChargeCompanyModel ChargeCompany { get; set; }

    public ChargeTypeModel ChargeType { get; set; }
    }
    }


     namespace Charge.Controllers
     {
     public class ChargeController : Controller
    {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Main()
    {
        var chargeEntities = new ChargeEntities();
        var sell = new SellChargeModel();
        var query = chargeEntities.ChargeCompanies.ToList();
        var listCompany =
            query.Select(
                company => new SelectListItem {Text = company.Name, Value =                         company.Id.ToString()})
                .ToList();
        sell.Companys = listCompany;
        return View(sell);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Main(FormCollection form)
    {
        var id = Convert.ToInt32(form["Companys"]);
        var chargeEntities = new ChargeEntities();
        var query = chargeEntities.ChargeTypes.Where(x => x.CompanyId == id).ToList();
        var chargeType = new SellChargeModel();
        var selectList = query.Select(x => new SelectListItem {Text = x.Type, Value = x.Id.ToString()}).ToList();
        chargeType.types = selectList;
        return View(chargeType);
    }

     }
     }

  @model SellChargeModel
  @using Charge.Models
 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Main";
}

  <h2>Main</h2>
   @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "dForm" }))
  {
  <div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Companys, Model.Companys, new {onchange =             "$('#dForm').submit()"})
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>
    @foreach (var c in Model.types)
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ChargeType, c.Text, c.Value)
        @Html.Label(c.Text)
    }
  </div>

   }
```

Comment: What does the constructor for `ChargeEntities();` look like?

Answer (score 1):

In your `[HttpPost]` action you need to set the `chargeType.Companys` property the same way you did in your `[HttpGet]` action (by using `chargeEntities.ChargeCompanies` and then mapping it to a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`). The reason you need to do this is because you are redisplaying the same view in which you are showing a dropdownlist depending on this property. And if the property is null, well, you get NRE in the view when you attempt to show the DropDownList.

Comment: you are right but before postback dropdown is done i have this error

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MCV does not have ViewState. So it will not keep your data across your postbacks for dropdowns. That is ASP.NET MVC behaviour. The reason you are getting a null error is beause in your post action method you are returning an object whose Companys properties is null. You may want to reload the data in that property before returning it like how you did in your HttpGet action method

Comment: you are right but before postback dropdown is done i have this error

Comment: @Mohsen: Use breakpoints in your HttpGet action method and see whether you are retuning null as companies

Comment: :in HttpGet action, companies is not null. the problem is types.beacuse types must be fill in httppost action and httpget action is empty